# How to set XP desktop background on just one monitor?

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization

Running XP with dual monitors, how can you set the desktop background on JUST ONE monitor?

---

Update: There is a method/tool described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/dual-monitors-use-a-different-wallpaper-on-each-desktop-in-vista-or-xp/) that seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.displayfusion.com/ is another one

Comment: I like the free version of Display Fusion (which is all it pretty much does on the free version). But the devs at our company really like the full version Display Fusion.

Comment: Yup - this is what I went with.  See the link in the update.

Answer (score 2):

Ultramon is a nice program to configure multiple screen set ups on Windows:
http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Not sure if it answers your question, because I have not used it for a long time, but its worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the nVidia Control Panel has that capability but you do have to be using one of their adapters.

Comment: Interesting..  I have that installed but can't see how to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I remembered this from an old gaming machine .. can't even begin to explain where it might be